# Excel How To Get Values From Another Excel with Fullpath?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I want to copy the data from a closed file I have selected and see it in the file containing this macro.

I am using Office365.

How can i copy data from this "FullPath" workbook ?

```
Private Sub PathName()
    Dim FullPath As String
    On Error GoTo extApp
    FullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="File Filter," & _
    "*.xls;*.doc;*.xlsx;*.mdb;*.ppt;*.pdf", Title:="Please Select A File")
        
            Exit Sub
    extApp: Select Case Err.Number
        
            Case 104
                MsgBox ("104")
                Exit Sub
        
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Runtime Error:  " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
                Stop
                Resume
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need to handle all of those file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following code modication, add in your other part of code to make it work as a complete sub:

```
Private Sub PathName()

Dim FullPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
On Error GoTo extApp
FullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="File Filter," & _
"*.xls;*.doc;*.xlsx;*.mdb;*.ppt;*.pdf", Title:="Please Select A File")
    
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullPath, , True)

wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Copy
Sheet1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'
'
'
wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```